# Зачем в файл манифеста war архива добавляется Class-path?

Tags: java

Добрый день!

В файл манифеста war архива добавляется Class-path, зачем это нужно? Ведь все зависимости обязаны помещаться в lib папку. Тоесть я хочу сказать, что это избыточно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Суть как раз в том что бы иметь возможность указывать пути которые не используются по-умолчанию.

Comment: в таком случае, их можно не класть в  lib ?